# python logging dictConfig custom formatter is not being called

Tags: python, logging, formatter, python-logging

i have the following ColoeredFormatter in my Module.

But The Formatter does not get called. I expect "hi" on the console, but i get "This is an info of the root logger".

i've already deleted all .pyc files, but it did not help.

**MyModule/__init__.py**

```
from MyModule.ColoredFormatter import ColoredFormatter

__all__ = ('ColoredFormatter')
```

**MyModule/ColoredFormatter.py**

```
import logging

class ColoredFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, default):
        self.default = default

    def format(self, record):
        print("hi")
        record.msg = "hi"
        return self.default.format(record)
```

**My Script**

```
import logging, logging.config, yaml

conf="""
logging:
  version: 1
  disable_existing_loggers: true
  root:
    level: !!python/name:logging.NOTSET
    handlers: [console]
  handlers:
    console:
      class: logging.StreamHandler
      stream: ext://sys.stdout
      formatter: myFormatter
      level: !!python/name:logging.NOTSET

  formatters:
    myFormatter:
      class: !!python/name:MyModule.ColoredFormatter
"""
dict = yaml.parse(conf)
logging.config.dictConfig(dict["logging"])

logging.info("This is an info of the root logger")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd like to add that the callable accepts a factory in `dictConfig.` A shorthand to pass custom arguments to the constructor is to utilise lambda.

Example:

```py
from MyModule import ColoredFormatter

...
    'formatters':
        '()': lambda: ColoredFormatter(foo='bar', ...),
```

Answer (score 27):

in the formatter section i had to replace `class` by `()`

```
import logging, logging.config, yaml

conf="""
logging:
  version: 1
  disable_existing_loggers: true
  root:
    level: !!python/name:logging.NOTSET
    handlers: [console]
  handlers:
    console:
      class: logging.StreamHandler
      stream: ext://sys.stdout
      formatter: myFormatter
      level: !!python/name:logging.NOTSET

  formatters:
    myFormatter:
      '()': MyModule.ColoredFormatter
"""
dict = yaml.parse(conf)
logging.config.dictConfig(dict["logging"])

logging.info("This is an info of the root logger")
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you got to this information? I couldn't find it anywhere

Comment: @Hagai some information can be found in the [Python logging documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details).

Comment: Thanks @Evert, It was a bit hard to find, so for the next generations: you can find it in the "user-defined-objects" section https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#user-defined-objects

Comment: Is there a way to pass a `fmt` argument to the `ColoredFormatter`’s constructor?